# C Macro is not expanded within Macro

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

I am developing a application which interact with hardware with ioctls. I wrote some lower level api for performing device operations. I wrote some macros as wrappers. as following.

```
WRITE_REGISTER(99, REGISTER_ADDRESS( 10, SCKT0_REG) );
```

with gcc -E, 
I noticed inner macro is not getting expanded. Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Compiling source code snippet is given bellow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_REG_NAME_LENGTH                     32
#define MODULE_SEQUENCER                        20
#define SCKT0_REG                               11

struct register_struct
{
    unsigned int reg_addr;
    unsigned int reg_value;
    char    reg_name [MAX_REG_NAME_LENGTH];
    char    module_name[MAX_REG_NAME_LENGTH] ;

} register_st;


#define GET_REGISTER_ADDRESS(module_index, register_offset)                                                     \
                (module_index * (1 << BITS_PER_MODULE) + register_offset)                                       \

#define REGISTER_ADDRESS_(module_index, register_offset)                                              \
                {                                                                                               \
                    memset(&register_st, 0, sizeof(struct register_struct));                                    \
                    register_st.reg_addr = GET_REGISTER_ADDRESS(module_index, register_offset);                 \
                    memcpy(register_st.reg_name, STR(register_offset), sizeof(STR(register_offset)));           \
                    memcpy(register_st.module_name, STR(MODULE_SEQUENCER), sizeof(STR(MODULE_SEQUENCER)));       \
                }                                                                                               \

#define REGISTER_ADDRESS(x, y) REGISTER_ADDRESS_(x, y)

#define WRITE_REGISTER(register_value, register_offset)                 \
                     ({                                                 \
                        register_st.reg_value = register_value;         \
                     })                                                 \

int main()
{
    unsigned int uiValue = 0;

    WRITE_REGISTER(99, REGISTER_ADDRESS( 10, SCKT0_REG) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With your updated code, when I run `gcc -E`, the macro gets expanded just fine, and the line in question expands to `({ register_st.reg_value = 99; });`.  But did you intend to have the `WRITE_REGISTER` macro actually do something with its second argument?  As written it doesn't use it at all, so its value is not included in the macro expansion.

Comment: This is one way that a macro is different from a function: all the arguments of a function are evaluated, even if the function doesn't use them.  But for a macro, if the name of a parameter doesn't appear in the macro definition, then any value passed as that parameter will just be dropped and will never appear in the program.

Comment: Actually, your whole design seems quite strange, because `REGISTER_ADDRESS` looks as though it's meant to be used like a function returning a value, but its expansion is a block rather than an expression.  I wonder if you might find it less confusing to rewrite these as inline functions instead of macros?  It should be just as efficient if your compiler is at all decent.